# Display Uri in ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I have a Uri of captured image from camera as "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Colony_Quantifier/IMG_20160523_204353.jpg".

While I am trying to show that image in ImageView, I am not being able to do it no matter whichever options suggested in internet.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Colony_Quantifier/IMG_20160523_204353.jpg");
imgCaptured.setImageURI(uri);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Picasso:

Include this line in your module level build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

then use it as:

```
Picasso.with(yourContext).load(uri).into(yourImageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));
```

Or:

```
ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You create a Bitmap out of the URI

2- You create a new instance of BitmapDrawable passing in the Bitmap

3- You add the BitmapDrawable to a Window (setBackgroundDrawable), View (setBackgroundDrawable)] or ImageView (setImageDrawable)